# Click on element with selenium2 in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Some elements are not clicked with selenium2 in IE

Throws Error: The point at which the driver is attempting to click on the element was not scrolled into the viewport. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Browser: IE 11
IEDriverServer: 2.39
Selenium server: 2.37

Tried with IEDriverServer 2.28, click works but there are some other things that does not work being an old version.
Tried with jquery click but it gives problems with other testcases.

Please post solutions or suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: IE11 isn't supported, so I wouldn't be too surprised if it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

Officially IE11 isn't in the support list of WebDriver currently, still for a work around you may try moving the focus on element first and then perform the click and if this fails you can try clicking using javascript click method

```
try {
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("XPATH_HERE"));
    if (element != null) {
        action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
        element.click();
        return;
    }
    throw Exception("Element not found to perform click");
}catch (Exception e) {
    try {
        (new JavascriptLibrary()).executeScript(driver, "arguments[0].click()", driver.findElement(By.xpath("XPATH_HERE")));
        return;
        }
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Javascript works but, just wanted a solution with selenium itself. Will try focusing on element as you suggest. Thanks!